# Determine If String Has All Same Character

Tags: c++

Is there a function like `find_first_not_of` that returns true or false as opposed to a position? I do not need the position, but rather whether or not the string contains all of the same char.

Comment: Simply compare the return value of `find_first_not_of()` against `std::string::npos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own function:

```
bool all_chars_same(string testStr) {
    char letter = testStr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < testStr.length(); i++) {
        if (testStr[i] != letter)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or use the built in `find_first_not_of`:

```
bool all_chars_same(string testStr) {
    return testStr.find_first_not_of(testStr[0]) == string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the value returned by `find_first_not_of` for [`string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

```
// needs to check if str.size() > 0
bool all_same = str.find_first_not_of(str[0]) == string::npos;
```

Alternatively, since you're looking for a single character, there's also [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

```
bool all_same = std::all_of(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), [&](char c){ return str[0] == c; });
```

Answer (score -1):

use yourstring.find(keyword);
you can get detail here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Answer (score -2):

I would recomend a define, it is the faster way.

```
#define find_not_of(a) (a.find_first_not_of(a[0]) != std::string::npos)
```

Comment: Prefer function to MACRO.

Comment: Any compiler worth is salt would be able to automatically inline this function call. There's no point in using a macro here.

Answer (score -2):

The best way and the quickest i can of is create a map and put the first value of the string as the key of the map. then iterate through the string and once you find one characters that is not in the map , you are done

```
 bool allSameCharacters ( string s){
  unordered_map < char , int> m;
  // m.reserve(s.size());
  m[s[0]]++;
  for (char c : s ){
    if (m.find(c) == m.end()) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Very inefficient. Just check every character against the first.